# With Nvidia proprietrary drivers cannot choose monitor launcher appears on

Tags: unity, nvidia, multiple-monitors, launcher

It's awesome that in 12.04 Unity now lets you choose on which monitor you want the unity launcher to appear.

However, once I've installed the nvidia proprietary drivers I can't chose anymore. I force what normally is my secondary monitor as a primary so that the launcher appears on it.

Is there a way to fix this, without having to set as primary the monitor where you want the launcher to appear?

I doubt there is a graphical solution, but what file do I need to edit?

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 you can choose which display (or all displays) the launcher appears in. This question is about 12.04 or earlier which are EOL. As such VTC as `not reproducible`.